# Morris.js Tooltips For Events

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I use morris.js to show different trends overlaid with media events. How can I add tooltips to the media events? I have read to docs for Morris.js and can't seem to find a solution. Does anyone know of any workaround to add tooltips to the events?